# Pass model to MVC controller

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

So I'm having an issue passing a param through to my controller.

When I do my Ajax.BeginForm and pass in as follows:

```
<% Using Ajax.BeginForm("MultiProcess", "Orders", New MultiProcessRequestViewModel With {.SearchParams = Model.SearchParams},New AjaxOptions With {.UpdateTargetId = "ordersOutput", .OnSuccess = "afterRead", .LoadingElementId = "readingOrders"})%>
```

The value appears as *'Nothing'*.

However on the same page if I simply do the following:

```
<%=New JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model.SearchParams) %>
```

To try and gauge if the value is set. I can see that the value is indeed set and correct.

The entire section for reference:

```
<% Using Ajax.BeginForm("MultiProcess", "Orders", New MultiProcessRequestViewModel With {.SearchParams = Model.SearchParams}, New AjaxOptions With {.UpdateTargetId = "ordersOutput", .OnSuccess = "afterRead", .LoadingElementId = "readingOrders"})%>
    <%=New JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model.SearchParams) %>

        <div>
            <%=Html.Hidden("SearchParams", Model.SearchParams) %>
            <%=Html.Hidden("Test", "Just in case") %>
            <%=Html.DropDownList("Process", Model.Processes)%>
            <input type="submit" value="Process selected items" class="FormButton" id="btnMultiProcess" />
            <br />
        </div>  

<%  End Using %>
```

The test and process params both work. Here is the model for reference:

```
Public Class MultiProcessRequestViewModel
    Public Property SearchParams As New Orders.OrderSearchFilters
    Public Property Process As String
    Public Property SelectedItems As New List(Of String)
    Public Property Test As String

End Class
```

Comment: `SearchParams` is a complex object and will not be serialized by `BeginForm()` (or any other method that generates a `RouteValueDictionary`)